# Trying to package a tiledmap so I can load it, tmx file not being created

Tags: java, libgdx

so i have a tmx file and a tileset png image in the folder `raw/`. I target the output to be in `assets/tiles/` which exists. When I run the following command:

```
java -classpath libs/gdx.jar:libs/gdx-tools.jar com.badlogic.gdx.tools.imagepacker.TexturePacker raw/ assets/tiles/
```

I get the following output:

```
raw
Format: RGBA8888 (default)
Filter: Nearest, Nearest (default)
Packing... ground
Packing... metatiles32x32
Writing 512x512: assets/tiles/raw1.png
Pixels eliminated: -271.0145%
```

No .tmx file is created. Any ideas as to what im missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the command I am using is depricated. Used the one here and it seems to work. Still some other things to work out, but the file loads: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/GraphicsTileMaps